# How to convert unsigned char[] to std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass this to another part of my project that requires it be a vector

```
unsigned char vch[65];

unsigned int size() const { return GetLen(vch[0]); }
const unsigned char* begin() const { return vch; }
const unsigned char* end() const { return vch + size(); 


std::vector<unsigned char> Raw() const
{
        return (vch, vch + size());
}
```

I get the error

```
 could not convert '(const unsigned char*)(&((const CPubKey*)this)-
CPubKey::vch)' from 'const unsigned char*' to 'std::vector<unsigned char*>'
```

Comment: `std::vector` has a constructor that takes a pair of iterators. Use that. You are pretty close.

Comment: The error message says `std::vector<unsigned char*>`  - note the `*` , probably you mistakenly wrote this `*` in one of your prototypes

Comment: There's a typo: `end()` is missing its closing `}`.

Comment: why not just use string? isn't it a kind of vector?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
return (vch, vch + size());
```

This uses the comma operator - long story short, write

```
return std::vector<unsigned char>(vch, vch + size());
```

or

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec(vch, vch + size())
return vec;
```

instead. (The latter is semantically equivalent but preferable in terms of readability)
Or with C++11:

```
return {vch, vch + size()};
```

This does work because a braced-init-list with pointers cannot be converted to `initializer_list<unsigned char>`. [over.match.list]/1:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized such
>   that 8.5.4 specifies that overload resolution is performed according
>   to the rules in this section, overload resolution selects the
>   constructor in two phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` [..]
> - **If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the
>        candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements
>       of the initializer list.**

Now, is there a viable initializer-list constructor? [over.ics.list]:

> 4. Otherwise, if the parameter type is `std::initializer_list<X>` **and all the elements of the initializer list can be implicitly converted
>      to `X`**, [..]
>
> 10. In all cases other than those enumerated above, **no conversion is possible.**

There is clearly no implicit conversion from `unsigned char*` to `unsigned char`, so the iterator-pair constructor template is chosen. [**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ffe0704f82d9574).

Comment: Even if it was, it wouldn't work. `std::initializer_list` is greedy. Note that [tag:c++] implies all versions by default. If you want version specific things, then they should add a tag saying that such as [tag:c++03].

Comment: @Rapptz Added standard quotes and a demonstration to make clear that it works. :)

Comment: I'd advise `std::vector<unsigned char> Raw() const
{std::vector<unsigned char> retval(vch, vch + size()); return retval;
}` in C++03 myself.  The cost (NRVO and RVO both eliminate the copy) remains the same, but we don't do 2 things on one line needlessly.  But this may be a matter of taste.

Comment: @Yakk You're absolutely right. Mind if I incorporate that into my answer?

Comment: @Columbo Why else would I add a comment?  :)

Answer (score 0):

It is may not answering directly to the answer.

But the question is why to use a vector when you can use  `std::string`, or `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` instead of std::vector, like this:

```
unsigned char a[]="1234";
std::basic_string<unsigned char> v=a;
```

Comment: Why do you consider `basic_string<unsigned char>` preferable to `vector` ?